# Get percentages of total

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am developing a program to find the file sizes of a couple folders and display their percentages relative to the total available. Here is my code.

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set item=0
set total=0
cd..
cd..
cd..
cd..
echo In location %cd%
cd folder1
call :size
cd..
cd folder2
call :size
cd..
cd folder3
call :size
cd..
cd folder4
call :size
cd..
echo.
echo.
echo Compared to total used:
echo total: !total!
echo.
set /A int1=100*!person1! / !total!
echo 1: !int1! percent
set /A int2=100*!person2! / !total!
echo 2: !int2! percent
set /A int3=100*!person3! / !total!
echo 3: !int3! percent
set /A int4=100*!person4! / !total!
echo 4: !int4! percent
echo.
echo.
echo Compared to total available:
```

**Here is the problem**

```
set total=275000
echo total: !total!
echo.
set /A int1=100*!person1! / !total!
echo 1: !int1! percent
set /A int2=100*!person2! / !total!
echo 2: !int2! percent
set /A int3=100*!person3! / !total!
echo 3: !int3! percent
set /A int4=100*!person4! / !total!
echo 4: !int4! percent`

pause >nul

exit

:size
set /a item=%item%+1
set /a value=0
set /a sum=0
FOR /R %1 %%I IN (*) DO (
set /a value=%%~zI/1024
set /a sum=!sum!+!value!
)
echo.
@echo %CD%:!sum! k
set person!item!=!sum!
set /a total=!total!+!sum!
goto :EOF
```

The problem I have is with the compared to total available section. I can do the percentages of space used, but I am having trouble with getting the percentages against the maximum total space the folders are allowed to take up. I get some crazy numbers that are above 100% when they shouldn't be.

Comment: `cmd` is limited to 32bit Integer. (Did you happen to see `Invalid number. Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision`?) To work with really big numbers, use anything other than batch.

Comment: Not difficult in PowerShell. Would you like to learn what Microsoft says is the future?

Comment: @Stephan So it doesn't have to do with my formula being wrong, the numbers are just too large?

Comment: @lit What, that they won't support batch? I hope I don't live to see that day, I have a ton of code that I've written in batch.

Comment: You also do not need to use delayed expansion.  Nor do you need to use the expansion characters(%%!!) at all for the evaluation when using `SET /A`.

Comment: @Squashman I think I had some problem with getting the values where I decided I needed to use it.

Comment: very much looks so. I tried it with some little folders and your logic seems to work so far. Using bigger folders and I get errors "invalid number..."

Comment: @Stephan Is the total size of the large folders >275000? I never got that error.